# How to get Gitlens to display inline blame annotations again?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

I am using Visual Studio Code

```
Version: 1.77.0:
Commit: 7f329fe6c66b0f86ae1574c2911b681ad5a45d63
Date: 2023-03-29T10:05:35.165Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.19.0-38-generic
Sandboxed: No
```

under Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and love the Gitlens 13.4.0 extension. But since quite a while it doesn't display any inline blame annotations any more in my repository, and I don't know what is wrong and how to fix it.

I am NOT in Zen (or review) mode, use no virtual drives at all and the "Current line blame" mode is enabled, but no blame annotations can be seen anymore. *And this is just for one repository I am working with. Another repository works just fine* - blame annotations are being displayed. There is no difference in the workspace settings files for these two repositories. I disabled ALL other addons, but to no avail.

I really don't know what's wrong and how to fix it - any hint really welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *deleted the repository locally and cloned it again* - did not touch any VSC configuration or workspace file at all - and now it works like a charm!

Hopefully, this insight will help other poor souls in the future.

Comment: This solved my issue! I encountered this issue specifically when my Gitlens Pro trial expired. Once I bought the subscription and then cloned a fresh copy of the repo it worked again. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

go to settings.json in '.vscode' folder.
remove the following line:

```
"search.followSymlinks": false,
```

it will work again.

Comment: I will happily accept this answer as soon as someone can confirm that this works, as it's e better way of solving it. Unfortunately, I currently can't check this myself.

Comment: I had the same issue with Inline Blame not showing. Adding this setting fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but deleting the repo and cloning it again did not help. Have tried to deactivate all other extensions, reset GitLens settings, no zen/review-mode, enabled inline blame, tried in both VS Code and VS Code Insider, the workspace settings are identical - Yet still inline blame is not working in repo B while it's working in repo A.

Current VS Code version:

```
Version: 1.81.1
Commit: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794
Date: 2023-08-09T22:40:25.698Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 22.3.18
ElectronBuildId: 22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.5.0
```

I'm out of ideas what to try next.. Anyone else having a clue?

**EDIT**

✅ GitLens debug logs showed a line `"document is not blameable"`. This clue led me the the issue [Blame is not working #1143](https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/issues/1143) and the solution that finally worked for me. I had to add an empty file `.git-blame-ignore-revs` in my project root, and then add the following to my `.git/config` file:

```
[blame]
   ignoreRevsFile = .git-blame-ignore-revs
```